# Translating Dijkstra's Algorithm from Python to C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm going through the book Grokking Algorithms which is in Python but wanted to write everything in C++. Up to this point everything's been pretty straightforward translation but the code for Dijkstra's algorithm really exploits nested dictionaries and weak typing which I used as an excuse to try out `std::optional`. I also am playing around with `std::set`, `std::unordered_map`, and using `typedef` to alias ugly types for the first time.

I've retained the original script-like functionality of the original code and have thrown everything into `main`, and know that a real implementation would be nicely put into a separate function. I am also aware that a real implementation would use a priority queue for finding the minimum cost edge rather than a linear search and wasn't really interested in Dijkstra's but moreso in the C++.

## What to Review

Primarily interested in knowing about my usage of `typedef` in this way, as well as if there was a better way than using `std::optional` and `std::nullopt` to handle translating from Python's `None` type.

## C++17 Code

Translated from [Python](https://github.com/egonSchiele/grokking_algorithms/blob/master/07_dijkstras_algorithm/python/01_dijkstras_algorithm.py) from Grokking Algorithms book.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<string, double> CostGraph;
typedef unordered_map<string, optional<string>> ParentGraph;
typedef unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, double>> WeightedGraph;

auto find_lowest_cost_node(CostGraph costs, const set<string>& processed) {
  auto lowest_cost = numeric_limits<double>::max();
  optional<string> lowest_cost_node = nullopt;
  for (const auto [node, cost] : costs) {
    if (cost < lowest_cost && find(processed.begin(), processed.end(), node) == processed.end()) {
      lowest_cost = cost;
      lowest_cost_node = node;
    }
  }
  return lowest_cost_node;
}

int main() {
  WeightedGraph graph;
  graph["start"] = {};
  graph["start"]["a"] = 6;
  graph["start"]["b"] = 2;

  graph["a"] = {};
  graph["a"]["fin"] = 1;

  graph["b"] = {};
  graph["b"]["a"] = 3;
  graph["b"]["fin"] = 5;

  graph["fin"] = {};

  CostGraph costs;
  costs["a"] = 6;
  costs["b"] = 2;
  costs["fin"] = numeric_limits<double>::max();

  ParentGraph parents;
  parents["a"] = "start";
  parents["b"] = "start";
  parents["fin"] = {};

  auto processed = set<string>{};

  while (const auto node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs, processed)) {
    const auto cost = costs[node.value()];
    const auto neighbours = graph[node.value()];

    for (const auto [n, c] : neighbours) {
      const auto new_cost = cost + c;
      if (costs[n] > new_cost) {
          costs[n] = new_cost;
          parents[n] = node;
        }
    }
    processed.insert(node.value());
  }

  cout << "Costs\n";
  for (const auto [k, v] : costs) {
    cout << k << ": " << v << "\n";
  }

  cout << "Parents\n";
  for (const auto [k, v] : parents) {
    if (v) {
      cout << k << ": " << v.value() << "\n";
    } else {
      cout << k << ": None\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Small comment to get you started: [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), and use [`using` instead of `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11), e.g. `using CostGraph = std::unordered_map<std::string, double>;`

Comment: Literal translations of algorithms between languages is unwise. The standard idioms of the language will not be used correctly.

Comment: Here is a close translation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448361/14065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid translating Pythonisms

> Dijkstra's algorithm really exploits nested dictionaries and weak typing which I used as an excuse to try out std::optional.

No, [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) does not require nested dictionaries nor weak typing. Maybe the Python implementation you are translating used these things, but maybe just because it was convenient in Python.

I strongly advise you to try to write idiomatic C++ code, not idiomatic Python translated to C++. What is convenient in Python might not be the best fit for C++, especially not when it comes to performance. I recommend you try to implement Dijkstra's using a [priority queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Furthermore, putting everything into `main()` is bad practice. It's better to organize your code into functions and classes as appropriate, and that's true even in Python.

## Use of typedefs

It's always a good idea to give a name to things, including types, that you use in multiple places in your code. However, in this case I think it would be better to create a `class WeightedGraph` that contains all the information about a graph with weighted edges. Then you can add member functions to this graph to add and remove vertices and edges, and a member function `get_shortest_path()` that uses Dijkstra's to calculate the shortest path between two given vertices and returns the list of vertices.

## Use of `std::optional`

While it's possible to use `std::optional` here to represent the parent of a vertex, it might not be necessary. If you represent vertices by their name, then an empty string for the name might be used as the equivalent of `None`. And a more idiomatic C++ implementation of this algorithm would probably store each vertex's parent vertex using a pointer, in which case the `nullptr` would be the equivalent of `None`.